# how to change a link tag: Submit to Anchor

Tags: struts, hyperlink, submit, tags, anchor

Question> How can I change `<s:submit>` to `<s:a>` in struts tag?

I want to send parameters to next page(action) by post (not get)

```
<s:form action="products" method="post" theme="simple">
  <s:hidden name="code" value="%{code}"/>
  <s:submit type="button" method="selectSale" value="see"/>
</s:form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not stated here but it looks like you have set 's' as the prefix for the struts-html taglib, i.e.:
`<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="s" %>`

Given this, there is no  tag, you will have to submit the form from a regular anchor tag using javascript yourself.  See the [struts FAQ](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-taglib/faq.html#javascript.submit).